# In Oracle, Can you create a new table with the same groups if you use CTAS Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, copy, sql-grant

I use the query CTAS to create a new table, however, when CTAS has finished, other users can´t select the new table, but they had access to the old, Is it a way to pass all the users and groups to the new table? because the old table will be deleted.

Comment: how the users is query the new table ? what way they are doing this ?

Comment: We are deleting some rows from tables with more than 10M of records and due to the indexes, if we run a delete from, the process takes a lot of time than the CTAS query, and the end user wants to preserve the table until the process has finished and they be sure the info deleted was the correct, you know, end user rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A way" is to grant (at least) `select` privileges to all those users.

If you used a role and granted `select` privilege to that role, and then granted role to those users, things would be quite simpler - just grant `select` privilege on the new table to the same role, and everyone will "see" it.

Otherwise, you can write query to create those `grant` statements for you.

For example, in Scott's schema there's the `EMP` table. I've previously granted privileges on it to other users in my database, and now I'm going to create a "new" CTAS table and grant privileges to the same set of users.

```
SQL> create table my_new_table as select * from emp;

Table created.

SQL> select 'grant select on my_new_table to ' || grantee ||';' run_me
  2  from all_tab_privs_made
  3  where owner = 'SCOTT'
  4    and table_name = 'EMP';

RUN_ME
---------------------------------------------------------------
grant select on my_new_table to SYS;
grant select on my_new_table to SUPERUSER;
grant select on my_new_table to MY_ROLE;
grant select on my_new_table to MIKE;
```

Now simply copy/paste the above bunch of `grant` statements:

```
SQL> grant select on my_new_table to SYS;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on my_new_table to SUPERUSER;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on my_new_table to MY_ROLE;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on my_new_table to MIKE;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

---

If there's *zillion* of users, PL/SQL option would be simpler as it would do everything for you (i.e. no copy/pasting):

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select grantee
  3                  from all_tab_privs_made
  4                  where owner = 'SCOTT'
  5                    and table_name = 'EMP'
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      execute immediate 'grant select on my_new_table to ' || cur_r.grantee;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table using CTAS from an existing one, the new one is a new segment, therefore it lacks of privileges. You need to recover the permissions granted to the old table and granting to the new one. For that you can use several alternatives ( dbms_metadata, dynamic sql ).

For the purposes , I'd do it like this

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE T2 AS SELECT * FROM T1 ;

    SQL> begin
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 
  'SQLTERMINATOR', true);  
       dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', 
    true);
    end;
    /
 
    select replace(dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', 'T1', 'OWNER_OF_T1' ),'T1','T2') AS ddl
    from   dual;
```

The first part is for creating in a nice format the list of necessary grants. The second part retrieves all the privileges granted to T1 and generates the list of grants statements for running to the T2 table. Then you only need to run the list of grants

As I said, there are several alternatives to do this.

Regards